# Scrape inline div values with Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am experimenting with Puppeter. I can read the data between  tags etc. Now I am trying to understand if I can also scrape inline elements an example div is eg:

```
<div class="distance-info-text distance font-xs-light" data-lat="50.912758301334" data-lng="6.019417197437" data-nid="153">83.8&nbsp;km</div>
```

For example, now I would like the inline elements:

```
data-lat = "50.912758301334" data-lng = "6.019417197437"
```

want to scrape, is that possible with Puppeteer or not?

My job title looks like this:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');


const getParagraphs = async (url) => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(url)

        var movies = await page.evaluate(() => {
            var titlesList = document.querySelectorAll('distance-info-text');
            var movieArr = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < titlesList.length; i++) {
               movieArr[i] = {
              title: titlesList[i].innerText.trim(),
              summary: titlesList[i].nextElementSibling.innerText.trim()
            };
         }
         return movieArr;
         })

         fs.writeFile("./netflixscrape.json", JSON.stringify(movies, null, 3), (err) => {
            if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
            };
            console.log("Great Success");
            })

        browser.close();
};

module.exports = getParagraphs;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can easily do that using [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) property:

```
        var movies = await page.evaluate(() => {
            var titlesList = document.querySelectorAll('distance-info-text');
            var movieArr = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < titlesList.length; i++) {
               movieArr[i] = {
              title: titlesList[i].innerText.trim(),
              summary: titlesList[i].nextElementSibling.innerText.trim(),
              lat: titlesList[i].dataset.lat, // <-- using dataset property
              lng: titlesList[i].dataset.lng, // <-- using dataset property
            };
         }
         return movieArr;
         })
```